# Is there a contains class equivalent for css?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Is there a css contains in Selenium? There used to be: `a:contains('Log Out')` but this no longer works.

Is there a css equivlent for:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'dd')]
```

on https://stackoverflow.com/questions

How would I write the above as a CSS using contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp),

> The [attribute*="value"] selector is used to select elements whose
>   attribute value contains a specified value.

for your question, You can use like this code with `*=`

```
str = 'Logout' 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="%s"]' % str)
```